# the equivalent of protocols and delegates in C#

Tags: c#, ios, .net, objective-c, winforms

I want to know, the equivalent of protocols and delegates in C#.

So this is my protocol, the interface and the implementation of class that defined the protocol and the implementation of the class that conform with the protocol. I want to know the equivalent of this in c#. please :)

```
/******************************************/
// Communicator Protocol
@class Communicator

@protocol CommunicatorDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)communicator:(Communicator *)communicator receivedData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)fetchingFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;

@optional
- (void)anOptinalMethod;

@end

/******************************************/
// Communicator Class

@protocol CommunicatorDelegate;

@interface Communicator : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CommunicatorDelegate> delegate;

@end

/******************************************/
// Communicator Implementation

@implementation

-(void)someMethodThatFail:(NSError *)error;
{
    [self.delegate fetchingFailedWithError:error];
}

- (void)someMethodThatGetData:(NSData *)data;
{
    [self.delegate communicator:self receivedData:data];
}

@end

/******************************************/
// Interface of Some Class that conform with the protocol

#import "Communicator.h"

@interface SomeClass : NSObject <CommunicatorDelegate>

@end

/******************************************/
// Implementation of Some Class that conform with the protocol

- (void)communicator:(Communicator *)communicator receivedData:(NSData *)data;
{
    // Do something
}

- (void)fetchingFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: For people who are not familiar with Objective-C, what are the purposes of protocols and delegates in that language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct equivalent of protocol is interface.
Since obj-c delegates are not a language feature but merely a design concept, there’s no equivalent in C#.

Also, I strongly advise against reusing the object model between obj-c and C#. Even with the backend code like your example. The languages are too different.
For the tasks like your example I’d consider between following alternatives:

1. Use 2 C#’s events instead of your 2 delegate methods.
2. Use following prototype for your communication method: `void Communicate( Action<YourData> actionToRunOnData )`, invoke the action on success, and throw an exception on failure. FYI: `Action<YourData> actionToRunOnData` is the equivalent of `void(^)(YourData*)actionToRunOnData` block in obj-c.
3. (I usually prefer this one) Use following prototype for your communication method: `async Task<YourData> Communicate()`, and throw exceptions on failure.

P.S. Funfact: in C# terminology, stuff like `Action<YourData> actionToRunOnData` is called "delegate" - which has nothing in common with the obj-c delegates.

Comment: So this is kind of like a blocks in Objective C ... I mean action handler or completion handler.

Comment: If you could attach a code snippet it'd be a real help